# AlarmManager not firing

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I've been for two days (about 12 hours) searching for information about alarmmanager and broadcastreceiver and I manage to get it working but I'm experimenting a really weird issue.

I'm trying to fire a service which then fires an intentservice. Sometimes, it works, but then it just stops working. It's really weird but the solution is calling the broadcast receiver on the alarm intent and then changing the class to the service's one. As I said, that's really weird, but after doing that, it works for a while (until the third or fourth compile, then it stops working again).

I just cannot understand why it works sometimes but it don't some others.

Here's my broadcastreceiver class:

public class BootCompletat extends BroadcastReceiver{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if ((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))){
        Log.d("BOOT COMPLETAT!! Inicio el servei","Iniciat");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServeiConnexio.class));      
    }else if((intent.getAction() != null) && (intent.getAction().equals("com.example.primerprograma.ALARMA_DISPARADA"))){
        Log.d("ALARMA!! Inicio el servei","Iniciat");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, ServeiConnexio.class)); 
    }
    Log.d("Detecto un esdeveniment: ",intent.getAction().toString());
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Detecto un esdeveniment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public static void SetAlarm(Context context){
    Log.d("Crido l'alarma","Cridant");
    int act = 1;
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Crido l'alarma", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    // When it stops working, I change on the line below ServeiConnexio.class for BootCompletat.class
    // Then it starts working (it updates every second) and I change it back to ServeiConnexio.class. After that, it works for a while (???)
    Intent i = new Intent(context, ServeiConnexio.class);
    i.setAction("com.example.primerprograma.ALARMA_DISPARADA");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * act, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
}
```

}

Here's my ServiceClass:

public class ServeiConnexio extends Service {

```
// Definim les variables que utilitzarem
private ArrayList<String> params_conn = new ArrayList<String>();
private String[] conn_params = null;
private ServidorsSQL factory = null;
private Funcions funcions = new Funcions();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Iniciant servei", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("SERVEI - He entrat a onStart", "onStart");

    factory = new ServidorsSQL(this,"Servidors", null,9);
    Log.d("Carrego info de tots els servidors","Carrego dades");
    funcions.llegeix(params_conn, factory);

    // Calling alarm
    Log.d("Executo alarma","");
    BootCompletat.SetAlarm(this);

    // Search for data to create the intent
    // The loop works perfectly and the intentservice works like charm
    // So it doesn't have anything to do with the alarm not working
    for(int m=0;m<params_conn.size();m++){
        Log.d("Entro al servei: " + Integer.toString(m),"Executo ConnectaSSH");
        // Partim els resultats en un array per poder-los passar a l'intent

        conn_params = params_conn.get(m).split("\n");

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("Resultats", conn_params);
        i.setClass(ServeiConnexio.this,IntentServeiConnexio.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.d("Crido activity ConnectaSSH: " + Integer.toString(m),"IntentServeiConnexio");
        startService(i);
        Log.d("Finalitzo activity IntentServeiConnexio: ",Integer.toString(m));
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Servei destruït",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Any help will be appreciated, I'm getting desperate

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me :

```
    // Start service using AlarmManager
     try {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourService.class);

        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 20000 , pintent); //20 second
        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourService.class));
        Log.d(tag, "Timer Started..");


} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(tag, "timer error: "+e);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I'm not sure where's the difference between your code and mine but yours work like charm.

Thank you very much.